# Start python file from post-recieve

Tags: python, git

I have this post-receive hook

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=/home/prod/app --git-dir=/home/prod/chat.git/ checkout -f
        killall python3 &
        python3 /home/prod/app/server/server.py &
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

runs and checks out fine, but the server.py process is either not started or does not remain running afterwards. Is there any way to start a python script from the hook, and keep it running?

Comment: killall pyhton3 seems a bit drastic

Comment: Perhaps it's a race condition and 'killall python3 &' is executed just as the next live executes resulting in the script being killed. Try removing the ampersands from killall

Comment: rikAtee, that makes the hook hang on killall, if no python3 process is found :(